# How to remove outliers from multiple columns in pyspark using mean and standard deviation

Tags: pyspark, outliers

I have the below data frame and I want to remove outliers from defined columns. In the below example price and income. Outliers should be removed for each group of data. In this example its 'cd' and 'segment' columns. Outliers should be removed based 5 standard deviations.

```
data = [
  ('a', '1',20,10),   
  ('a', '1',30,16),
  ('a', '1',50,91),
    ('a', '1',60,34),
    ('a', '1',200,23),
  ('a', '2',33,87),
  ('a', '2',86,90),
      ('a','2',89,35),
    ('a', '2',90,24),
    ('a', '2',40,97),
  ('a', '2',1,21),
  ('b', '1',45,96),   
  ('b', '1',56,99),
  ('b', '1',89,23),
    ('b', '1',98,64),
    ('b', '2',86,42),
  ('b', '2',45,54),
  ('b', '2',67,95),
      ('b','2',86,70),
    ('b', '2',91,64),
    ('b', '2',2,53),
  ('b', '2',4,87)
]
data = (spark.createDataFrame(data, ['cd','segment','price','income']))
```

I have used the code below to remove outliers but this would work only for one column.

```
mean_std = (
    data
    .groupBy('cd', 'segment')
    .agg(
      *[f.mean(colName).alias('{}{}'.format('mean_',colName)) for colName in ['price']],
      *[f.stddev(colName).alias('{}{}'.format('stddev_',colName)) for colName in ['price']])
)


mean_columns = ['mean_price']
std_columns = ['stddev_price']
upper = mean_std
for col_1 in mean_columns:
    for col_2 in std_columns:
      if col_1 != col_2:
        name = col_1 + '_upper_limit'
        upper = upper.withColumn(name, f.col(col_1) + f.col(col_2)*5)
        
lower = upper
for col_1 in mean_columns:
    for col_2 in std_columns:
      if col_1 != col_2:
        name = col_1 + '_lower_limit'
        lower = lower.withColumn(name, f.col(col_1) - f.col(col_2)*5)
        
outliers = (data.join(lower, 
                                how = 'left',
                                on = ['cd', 'segment'])
                           .withColumn('is_outlier_price', f.when((f.col('price')>f.col('mean_price_upper_limit')) |
                                                           (f.col('price')<f.col('mean_price_lower_limit')),1)
                                                      .otherwise(None))
           )
```

my final output should have a column for each variable stating whether its 1 = remove or 0 = keep.

Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works almost 100% fine. All you have to do is to replace the single fixed column name with an array of column names and then loop over this array:

```python
numeric_cols = ['price', 'income']
mean_std = \
    data \
    .groupBy('cd', 'segment') \
    .agg( \
      *[F.mean(colName).alias('mean_{}'.format(colName)) for colName in numeric_cols],\
      *[F.stddev(colName).alias('stddev_{}'.format(colName)) for colName in numeric_cols])
```

`mean_std` is now a dataframe with two columns (`mean_...` and `stddev_...`) per element of `numeric_cols`.

In the next step we calculate the lower and upper limit per element of `numeric_cols`:

```python
mean_std_min_max = mean_std
for colName in numeric_cols:
    meanCol = 'mean_{}'.format(colName)
    stddevCol = 'stddev_{}'.format(colName)
    minCol = 'min_{}'.format(colName)
    maxCol = 'max_{}'.format(colName)
    mean_std_min_max = mean_std_min_max.withColumn(minCol, F.col(meanCol) - 5 * F.col(stddevCol))
    mean_std_min_max = mean_std_min_max.withColumn(maxCol, F.col(meanCol) + 5 * F.col(stddevCol))
```

`mean_std_min_max` now contains the two additional columns `min_...` and `max...` per element of `numeric_cols`.

Finally the join, followed by the calculation of the `is_outliers_...` columns as before:

```python
outliers = data.join(mean_std_min_max, how = 'left', on = ['cd', 'segment'])
for colName in numeric_cols:
    isOutlierCol = 'is_outlier_{}'.format(colName)
    minCol = 'min_{}'.format(colName)
    maxCol = 'max_{}'.format(colName)
    meanCol = 'mean_{}'.format(colName)
    stddevCol = 'stddev_{}'.format(colName)
    outliers = outliers.withColumn(isOutlierCol, F.when((F.col(colName) > F.col(maxCol)) | (F.col(colName) < F.col(minCol)), 1).otherwise(0))    
    outliers = outliers.drop(minCol,maxCol, meanCol, stddevCol)
```

The last line of the loop is only to clean up and drop the intermediate columns. It might be helpful to comment it out.

The final result is:

```
+---+-------+-----+------+----------------+-----------------+
| cd|segment|price|income|is_outlier_price|is_outlier_income|
+---+-------+-----+------+----------------+-----------------+
|  b|      2|   86|    42|               0|                0|
|  b|      2|   45|    54|               0|                0|
|  b|      2|   67|    95|               0|                0|
|  b|      2|   86|    70|               0|                0|
|  b|      2|   91|    64|               0|                0|
+---+-------+-----+------+----------------+-----------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the list comprehension using F.when.
A very simplified example of your problem:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
tst1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4,1,10),(1,3,5,7,2,11),(9,9,10,6,2,9),(2,4,90,9,1,2),(2,10,3,4,1,7),(3,5,11,5,7,8),(10,9,12,6,7,9),(3,6,99,8,1,9)],schema=['val1','val1_low_lim','val1_upper_lim','val2','val2_low_lim','val2_upper_lim'])
tst_res = tst1.select(tst1.columns+[(F.when((F.col(coln)<F.col(coln+'_upper_lim'))&(F.col(coln)>F.col(coln+'_low_lim')),1).otherwise(0)).alias(coln+'_valid') for coln in tst1.columns if "_lim" not in coln ])
```

The results:

```
tst_res.show()
+----+------------+--------------+----+------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|val1|val1_low_lim|val1_upper_lim|val2|val2_low_lim|val2_upper_lim|val1_valid|val2_valid|
+----+------------+--------------+----+------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|   1|           2|             3|   4|           1|            10|         0|         1|
|   1|           3|             5|   7|           2|            11|         0|         1|
|   9|           9|            10|   6|           2|             9|         0|         1|
|   2|           4|            90|   9|           1|             2|         0|         0|
|   2|          10|             3|   4|           1|             7|         0|         1|
|   3|           5|            11|   5|           7|             8|         0|         0|
|  10|           9|            12|   6|           7|             9|         1|         0|
|   3|           6|            99|   8|           1|             9|         0|         1|
+----+------------+--------------+----+------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However this is not the complete solution I am looking for. I would like to know how you calculated val1_low_lim and val1_upper_lim for each variable using the original data frame that I have shared ? Would be a great help if you could share this as well.

Comment: Ok, I assumed you calculate the limits with the for loops and are just looking for how to apply the F.when part for all the calculated limits